# How do i use context.Database.SqlQuery<T> in EF to execute a sql query which includes a sql function

Tags: sql, entity-framework

**See the following code.**

```
var labors = context.Database.SqlQuery<LaborViewModel>("with TempTable "
                + "as("
                + "select [UserName], [TotalCost], [TotalHours]"
                + " FROM [RetrieveLabors](1, 1)"
                + ") "
                + "select [UserName],"
                + "       sum([TotalCost]) [TotalCost],"
                + "       sum([TotalHours]) [TotalHours]"
                + " from TempTable group by [UserName]");
```

When running the below error shows.

An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function RetrieveLabors.
Please note the function has two parameters, and the values are there.

**I have tried all other ways like below:**

```
var labors = context.Database.SqlQuery<LaborViewModel>("with TempTable "
                + "as("
                + "select [UserName], [TotalCost], [TotalHours]"
                + " FROM [RetrieveLabors](1, 1)"
                + ") "
                + "select [UserName],"
                + "       sum([TotalCost]) [TotalCost],"
                + "       sum([TotalHours]) [TotalHours]"
                + " from TempTable group by [UserName]", new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@CultureId",
                Value = parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "CultureId").Value ?? DBNull.Value
            },
            new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@SiteId",
                Value = parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "SiteId").Value ?? DBNull.Value
            });
```

It still cannot work. Error is below:

The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

Is it my problem or EF's ?

Comment: Just wonder that what db you use?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MSSQL - you must specify the owner of the function, for example:

```
select [UserName], [TotalCost], [TotalHours]"
            + " FROM dbo.[RetrieveLabors](1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.
```

and

```
Value = parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "CultureId").Value ?? DBNull.Value
```

suggest to me that you are re-using your 'parameters' collection inappropriately. What you should probably do is to create a new SqlParameter when you execute; more like;

```
var existingCultureParameter = parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "CultureId");
SqlParameter newCultureParameter;
if (existingCultureParameter != null) {
    newCultureParameter = new SqlParameter("CultureId", existingCultureParameter.Value);
} else {
    newCultureParameter = new SqlParameter("CultureId", DbNull.Value);
}
```

Something roughly like that. You're just trying to avoid re-using the same parameter in different queries. The solution is probably more elegant elsewhere in your code.